# Pushing docker image to the target repository by aws-cdk

Tags: typescript, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I have two stacks `CdkVrStack` and `CdkVrDeployStack`

in `CdkVrStack`, repository my-repo-name is created.

```
export class CdkVrStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    const repo_ = new ecr.Repository(this, 'TestRepoId', {
      repositoryName: "my-repo-name",
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
    });
```

then in `CdkVrDeployStack` I try to upload the docker image

```
export class CdkVrDeployStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    //maybe repositoryName is deprecated, so how can I set the repository which CdkVrStack created
    
    this.synthesizer.addDockerImageAsset({
      directoryName: path.join(__dirname, 'app1'), 
      repositoryName: "my-repo-name", // this is deprecated how can I se the repository?
      sourceHash: "image-tag",
    });
  }
}
```

I can't compile CdkVrStack

```
lib/cdk_vr-deploy-stack.ts:19:7 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ directoryName: string; repositoryName: string; sourceHash: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DockerImageAssetSource'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'repositoryName' does not exist in type 'DockerImageAssetSource'.

19       repositoryName: "my-repo-name", 
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[0:39:30] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.

---

I tested this code in one stack, from this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecr_assets.DockerImageAsset.html)

```
const repo_ = new ecr.Repository(this, 'TestRepoId', {
  repositoryName: "my-repo-name",
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
});

new DockerImageAsset(this,'mydockerimageassets',{
  directory: path.join(__dirname, '../docker-lambda'),
  repository:repo_
});
```

However ,theter comes error

```
lib/cdk_vr-base-stack.ts:63:7 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ directory: string; repository: ecr.Repository; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DockerImageAssetProps'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'repository' does not exist in type 'DockerImageAssetProps'.

63       repository:repo_
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`repository` is the properties of `DockerImageAsset`, where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see a question or a problem statement. What isn't working? What do you need help with?

Comment: This isn't Python, so I've removed the tag. Please add the correct language tag

Comment: Assets are uploaded to the asset ECR repository, which is the same for all stacks. It's created as part of bootstrapping.

Comment: @MarkB I updated the article.

Comment: @OneCricketeer THank you . I wrongly attached `python`

Comment: @gshpychka I see,,, so bootstrap makes ECR repository, however how can I upload the docker image?? this typescript code can not be compiled.

Comment: Use the `ecr-assets` module: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecr_assets.DockerImageAsset.html

Comment: @gshpychka Thank you I am trying `DockerImageAssets`, however still have question, I updated the article.

Comment: Like I said, it uploads it to the asset repo, not a repo you can specify.

Comment: Thank you for your help. @gshpychaka , I use third-party tool and solve the problem. I answer this article by myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241451/discussion-between-gshpychka-and-whitebear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `https://github.com/cdklabs/cdk-ecr-deployment`

I can make repository and push image with this code.

```
import * as ecrdeploy from 'cdk-ecr-deployment';

    
const repo_ = new ecr.Repository(this, 'TestRepoId', {
  repositoryName: "my-repo-name",
  removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
});

const image_ = new DockerImageAsset(this,'mydockerimageassets',{
  directory: path.join(__dirname, '../docker-lambda'),
  
});
new ecrdeploy.ECRDeployment(this, 'DeployDockerImage', {
  src: new ecrdeploy.DockerImageName(image_.imageUri),
  dest: new ecrdeploy.DockerImageName(`${repo_.repositoryUri}:latest`),
});
```

Comment: FYI you're still uploading to the asset ECR repo, then copying it to your own repo.

Comment: Not really, by default `DockerImageAsset` won't push to any repo unless its attached to another resource. The `ECRDeployment` provides that attachment.

Comment: @whitebear, is there similar solution/library for python, please?